# Debugging Multiple Disposition Headers

Tags: http, google-chrome, http-headers

I am developing a web application using Java and keep getting this error in Chrome on some particular pages:

> net::ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

So, I checked WireShark for the corresponding TCP stream and this was the header of the response:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Mon, 10 Sep 2012 08:48:49 GMT
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=KBM 80 U (50/60Hz,220/230V)_72703400230.pdf
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 564449
X-Cache: MISS from my-company-proxy.local
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from my-company-proxy.local:8080
Via: 1.0 host-of-application.com, 1.1 my-company-proxy.local:8080 (squid/2.7.STABLE5)
Connection: keep-alive
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive

%PDF-1.4
[PDF data ...]
```

I only see **one** content disposition header in there. Why does chrome tell me there were several?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the filename parameter is unquoted, and contains a comma character (which is not allowed in unquoted values, and in this case indicates that multiple header values have been folded into a single one).

See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.4.2.p.5 and http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc6266.html